# Updating all instances of a model everyday in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, scheduled-tasks

First of all, I know this is not a general "stackoverflow" type of question, but I can't find another good website to ask this. I personally think this is a perfectly reasonable question, so I hope you can help me out here. Basically how can you make all the model instances updated on a daily basis in Django? Right now, I have a model that has each of my students' information. I want to update each of my students information everyday, so that the correct students will show up in my schedule list in django daily. For example, if it is a holiday, then a "show in my list" field in each student's model will be updated to false. Of course, I am going to add a lot of functions such as "is it a holiday today?", "does the student have a class with me today?", "at what time does the student have class with me today?", etc. If the student matches all of the requirements(or functions) to "show up" in my schedule, then the "show in my list" field in each student's model will be updated to true. My schedule list will then loop through all of my students to just display students with the "show in my list" field = True. So, I need a function(or a list of functions) to update each of my model instance daily. Any ideas or recommendations on how I can do this? A link to a video where it shows how I can do this would also be appreciated. I researched about scheduled tasks, but I don't really understand them. Since I am a beginner, I would also appreciate an "easy way" to do this task. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most preferable way to add a background and periodic tasks to your django project is [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/). Celery has integration with django and you can make a basic setup really quickly. Celery provides beat - a scheduler that will emit messages what task should be executed to the queue in your broker (Redis or RabbitMQ), worker - process, or a pool of processes that will read messages from the queue in your broker and execute necessary tasks. Observe docs for examples.

Another way - it's a simple thread that would be started with your django project and execute necessary things when you need. This way should be chosen if you need the only very basic setup for periodic tasks and you don't want to think about brokers and workers. For example in your app/apps.py:

```
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        # avoid double execution by checking 'autoreload' variable

        if environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) == 'true':
            return

        from .scheduler import Scheduler

        # scheduler will execute task every 10 seconds
        thread = Thread(
            daemon=True,
            target=Scheduler(10).run
        )

        thread.start()
```

And scheduler.py, uses [sched](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html#module-sched) from the standard library:

```
from sched import scheduler

class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self, delay: int):
        self.delay = delay
        self.scheduler = scheduler()

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            self.scheduler.enter(self.delay, 1, <some function>)
            self.scheduler.run()
```